# Difference between the printer drivers

Tags: windows, printing, virtual, drivers, wdk

My question is pretty simple but I am not able to find clean and simple to understand answer for a long time.

There are these printer drivers:

> Unidrv
>
> XPSdrv
>
> PostScript

**What are the differences between them? If Unidrv ( the universal printer driver can handle all types of printers ) then what is the need of other 2? Pros and cons of each?**

FYI, my scenario: I am in need of writing a virtual printer driver that emulates a printer and lists under available printers and when that printer is selected for printing from other applications, the driver should redirect the data to my program for other processing.